# How do make changes in drivers/etc/hosts take affect instantly with IE?

Tags: firefox, internet-explorer, hosts

Firefox will notice this change immediately,

but IE will need several minutes to take affect.

Is there somehow I can make it work faster?

Answer (score 0):

They are instant. Perhaps clearing your cache will fix it - or restarting IE.

Comment: I tried clearing the cache,doesn't work. It only works by restarting IE.How can I make it work without restarting?

Comment: Which version of IE? all of them?